# Python - Getting the word between two tags

Tags: python, xml, regex

I have this string:

```
História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares
```

And I want to get what is between `CATEG="(what I want to get)"`, and between `">(what I want to get)</EM>`, in this case the result would be `PESSOA` and `RFID`.

what I have is

```
pega = re.sub(r'<[^C]*(CATEG="[^"]+")[^>]*>', r'<\1>', text)
```

but the result is only

> História do RFID A tecnologia de RFID < tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares

How can I do it?

Comment: Post what you have tried please.

Comment: Is it always in between an EM tag?

Comment: @Jerry so far what I have is 'pega = re.sub(r'<[^C]*(CATEG="[^"]+")[^>]*>', r'<\1>', text)', but the result is only 'História do RFID A tecnologia de <CATEG="PESSOA">RFID < tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares'

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: Honestly using an HTML/XML parser will be less painful than devising a regular-expression.

Comment: So, is this not XML or SGML? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: @TiagoFróes It is polite to accept the best answer if your question has been properly answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily parse this using the built-in minidom module:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml = '<xml>História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares</xml>'
dom = minidom.parseString(xml)
em = dom.getElementsByTagName('EM')[0]
categ = em.getAttribute('CATEG')
text = " ".join(t.nodeValue for t in em.childNodes if t.nodeType == t.TEXT_NODE)
```

Or a less verbose way using the build-in ElementTree module:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml = '<xml>História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares</xml>'
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml)
em = tree.find('EM')
categ = em.attrib['CATEG']
text = em.text
```

Comment: It's almost like you're the only answerer who knows how to use something other than a regex.

Comment: @Marcin look how much longer it is than a simple `re.search`.

Comment: @Jerry Look how much more comprehensible and robust it is.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using beautifulsoup:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('''História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares''')
print soup.em['id']
print soup.em['categ']
```

You will note that this is the second most concise solution, and the most maintainable, because there are no complex expressions to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it's hard to say. The following may be too specific for your needs, but it does what you asked. Hopefully, it will get you started, at least.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                         

import re

text='História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares'

m = re.compile(r'CATEG="([^"]*)">([^>]*)</')
result = m.search(text)

print result.groups()
```

Output is:

```
('PESSOA', 'RFID ')
```

Comment: @Marcin: The OP gave a string which has SGML-like tags/attributes in it. We don't know where it came from, never mentioned XML/SGML, and specifically asked for a regex. It is a *huge* assumption that it's an XML fragment from a document to which, say, XPath can be applied.

Comment: @Emmet "specifically asked for a regex" Show me where.

Comment: @Marcin: When I answered the question, it was simply tagged "regex", *you* added the "XML". It's unacceptable to alter a question to support the assumption that you're downvoting people for. That's just outright dishonest.

Comment: @Emmet No, it's not. Sorry. Tags are there to help people locate questions. This appears to be about XML.

Comment: @Marcin Wow. You're the one making massive assumptions here. The OP never mentioned XML and there's nothing in the question to support the contention that it's XML, other than the tags. If the OP had extracted that from a well-formed XML document, do you not think he'd be able to extract something trivially more specific?

Comment: @Emmet It's sufficiently well formed that it can be parsed, especially by a quirks parser (e.g. beautiful soup). Such parsing is preferable to ad hoc regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `re.search`:

```
>>> result = re.search(r'CATEG="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)', text)
>>> print result.group(1)
PESSOA
>>> print result.group(2)
RFID
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iW8vP9).

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/K3HKtV).

Don't just print `result` because it is an object in python. You need to print them as strings and as such, you use `.group()` (if you put an integer `n` inside the brackets, you get the `n`th capture group).

Comment: @TiagoFróes You can accept an answer by clicking on the tick outline to the side of an answer.

Comment: @TiagoFróes I think you should also put in your question what you told me earlier about not being able to use anything else than regex.

Answer (score 1):

The split function may be an easy solution for this problem

```
s = "História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares"
# FOR PESSOA
t1 = s.split("CATEG=\"")[1]
t1 = t1.split("\"")[0]    
# FOR RFID
t2 = s.split(" </EM>")[0]
t2 = t2.split(">")[1]
print t1,t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r'.*?<EM.*?CATEG="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<//EM>.*?'
```

That would do it. group(1) would be your categ, and group(2) would be your tagged word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you may play with the standart's library **HTMLParser** (**not the best option**, but may be interesting):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    data = ""
    search_tag = None
    search_attr = None
    attr = None
    grab_data = False

    def to_dict(self, attrs):
        ret = {}
        for k, v in attrs: ret[k] = v
        return ret

    def feed(self, data, tag, attr):

        self.search_tag = tag
        self.search_attr = attr
        HTMLParser.feed(self, data)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):

        attrs = self.to_dict(attrs)
        if tag == self.search_tag:
            if self.search_attr in attrs:
                self.attr = attrs[self.search_attr]
            self.grab_data = 1

    def handle_data(self, data):

        if self.grab_data:
            self.data = data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):

        if tag == self.search_tag:
            self.grab_data = 0

xml = u'História do RFID A tecnologia de <EM ID="hub-30518" CATEG="PESSOA">RFID </EM>\
                                                tem suas raízes nos sistemas de radares'

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(xml, "em", "categ")
print parser.data, parser.attr
```